# 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint' SQL Error

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

This seems to be a pretty common question that is asked but, everything I have tried so far has left with with no solution.  I am using an ID field for my PK and auto increment has been turned on.  This is occurring in a DEV environment where data has been merged with the current data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using a SQL Server.  I have also ran DBCC CHECKIDENT([ceschema.ce_attendeeCredit]) and the identity seems to line up properly.  I think there may be a deeper issue in play.

```
INSERT INTO tblpersonCredit
                (
                personID,
                CreditID,
                Amount,
                ReferenceNo,
                CreatedBy
                )
            VALUES
                (
                <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.AttendeeCredit.getAttendeeID()#" CFSQLType="cf_sql_integer" />,
                <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.AttendeeCredit.getCreditID()#" CFSQLType="cf_sql_integer" />,
                <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.AttendeeCredit.getAmount()#" CFSQLType="cf_sql_float" null="#not len(arguments.AttendeeCredit.getAmount())#" />,
                <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.AttendeeCredit.getReferenceNo()#" CFSQLType="cf_sql_varchar" null="#not len(arguments.AttendeeCredit.getReferenceNo())#" />,
                <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.AttendeeCredit.getCreatedBy()#" CFSQLType="cf_sql_integer" />
                )
```

Comment: Table definition? What query are you running? For that matter, what RDBMS are you running on? Give us something more to work with here.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? If SQL Server has `DBCC CHECKIDENT ... RESEED` been run leaving the current seed smaller than the values in the table?

Comment: Some sample code, like an excerpt from the table definition would help. That error is usually caused by trying to insert a record with a key already used in the table.

Comment: Can you script out the table definition for `tblpersonCredit` and put that into your question? It looks like you were checking the identity column on table `ce_attendeeCredit` but your insert that fails in on an entirely different table that may well have a composite PK of `personID,CreditID`?

Answer (score 6):

I noticed this specific line in your question:

> This is occurring in a DEV environment where data has been merged with the current data.

After manually inserting data into an autoincrement field you may need to reset the autoincrement counter to something after the maximum id that you inserted.

How you do this (and whether you need to) is database dependent. For example in MySQL you can use an ALTER TABLE statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000
```

The equivalent command to reset the seed for an SQL Server IDENTITY column is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(tbl, RESEED, 9999)
```

Comment: I am using SQL server.  Resetting the auto increment seems to be pointing me to a lot (if not all) MySQL information.

Comment: @jslamka: That's because it's called IDENTITY in SQL SERVER. The term "auto increment" is used in MySQL.

Comment: @jslamka - You don't need to do this in SQL Server it does it automatically. If you `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` then insert some records higher than the current values then `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` it should reset the value of the seed automatically as far as I remember. Have you explicitly run `DBCC CHECKIDENT ... RESEED ` yourself?

Comment: @Martin I have tried to run it but, due to my ignorance I am running into other SQL issues.  I am getting a syntax error when trying to run DBCC CHECKIDENT(tbl, NORESEED) to get the current IDENTITY

Comment: @jslamka - Just run `DBCC CHECKIDENT(your_table_name)` and it should automatically set the seed value you need if that has somehow got out of synch. But what syntax error are you getting? That command looks like it should have worked as long as you used your actual table name and have appropriate permissions.

Comment: @Martin, I am not sure what I did but, it seems after I reran the statement you offered it worked.

Comment: @Martin Running `DBCC CHECKIDENT(your_table_name)` didn't reseed the table.  But it told me what the current identity is at and what it should be, which was very useful.  Then I ran `DBCC CHECKIDENT(your_table_name, RESEED, number_it_should_be)` and that worked.

Answer (score -2):

Use following logic before Insertion Query....
select MAX(ID) from Table;
  string queryInsertStudent = String.Format("insert into tbStudent(studentName,fatherName,programme,session,regNo,enrolNo,emailAddress,contactNo,CNIC,parmanentAddress,Status) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}');", Student_Name, F_Name, Programe, Session, RegNo, EnrollNo, Email, Contact, CNIC, Address, Status);
                //the above "  string queryInsertStudent" is string data type query for data insertion in the data table
                ClassDatabaseConnection.Excute(queryInsertStudent); //here "Execute is Method under the CLASS "DatabaseConnectionClass""
                string student_ID = ClassDatabaseConnection.select("select MAX(studentId) from tbStudent").Rows[0][0].ToString();