# SQL Server Primary key violation due to truncate/delete?

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, truncate

I've got a set of staging tables where I accept data, scrub, and cleanse them before inserting to the target table.  The target table has a primary key constraint and what I'm inserting is a primary key.

I check for the absence of the primary key in the target table before I insert.  I insert only records that ARE NOT in the target table, based on the primary key's absence:

```
INSERT INTO Target
    SELECT 
        primKey
        , user_state
        , test_state
    FROM
        myStagingTable3
```

By this point, the stagingTable3 has only data that are NOT present in the Target Table using the following where clause:

```
WHERE
        primKey not in (Select primKey from Target)
```

Somehow, I'm getting a primary key violation error :

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1.  (procedure failed at line #...)
>   Violation of Primary Key constraint 'pk1101AE.'  Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'Target'

My questions:

- under what conditions could a primary key violation occur when the
  key that I want to insert is NOT present in the target table?
- could a prior delete of records cause the primary key to be retained?  If so,
  can I work around this somehow?
- something else?

It's pretty clear that my staging tables have the key and that the Target table does not.  Yet the insert fails.

Comment: I should add that I read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278588/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-sql-error  And the delete / truncate issues are interesting.  Just don't know how to work around it.  Kind of a noob at this. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your staging table contains multiple values of `primKey`.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked... and that's true... it does have multiple values of primKey.  And that would mean the SECOND key value is what is causing the error, and so the whole thing bails and transaction is rolled back.  I might be looking at a MERGE statement here if I can't weed out the duplicates. That way, i can UPDATE after the insert too.  Always check the simple stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your staging table contains multiple rows with the same value of primKey.

If it does not matter to you which `{user_state, test_state}` pair among the duplicated ones makes it into the insert, you can bypass the issue entirely by adding a simple `group by`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Target
    (SELECT 
        primKey
    ,   MAX(user_state)
    ,   MAX(test_state)
    FROM
        myStagingTable3
    GROUP BY primKey)
```