# EF , SQL Server and duplicate PK error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wrote a program that is almost one year he was working properly but I recently added a new item in the database with error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Accounts'. Can not insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Accounts'. The duplicate key value is (110603267).

I faced. Nothing special happened, and I do not know why this error was given.
Id field for [Key], and is of type long. And is in the database for is identity.
Here's to say that any time you attempt to add a new item of the Id ( "110603267") was changed and the error was one other ID.

With ASP.NET MVC, EF is written. Please advise what to do to fix this problem. Thankful

my model :

```
public partial class Account
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckExistUser", "ManageAccount", ErrorMessage = "این نام کاربری قبلا ثبت شده", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "کد ملی 10 رقم می باشد")]
    [Display(Name = "کد ملی")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "رمز عبور")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]

    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "حداقل 6 کاراکتر")]

    //[DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "تکرار رمز عبور")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    // [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "عدم تطابق کلمه عبور")]
    public string PasswordRe { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "امضا")]
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="ایمیل")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("CheckExistEmail", "ManageAccount", ErrorMessage = "این ایمیل قبلا ثبت شده", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupID")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public long? GroupID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ActorID")]
    public virtual Actor Actor { get; set; }
    public long? ActorID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "شماره همراه")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

my code :

```
var tempAccount = new Account
{
    Name = tempCodeMeli,
    Password = SecurityManager.HashData(mobile),
    PasswordRe = SecurityManager.HashData(mobile),
    Mobile = mobile,
    IsActive = true,
  _ Date = DateTime.Now
};

dbContext.Accounts.Add(tempAccount);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: more details needed, esp of the existing code.

Comment: Can you show some code? Sounds like you're trying to insert an entity with an Id that already exists but needs to be unique.

Comment: And don't just paste **all** your code. Make a [MCVE] to illustrate your problem.

Comment: write your Account entity and the related db DbContext part and how you are calling it.

Comment: Duplicate key means you trying to insert a series of data to an entity with same PK as existing one. Usually it thrown when performing `DBContext.SaveChanges`.

Comment: We do not have the magic crystal to see your code, we can answer the question when you can describe  the problem in a good way.

Comment: How is your Id getting set?

Comment: مسعود look to @VojtěchDohnal answer I think it should work to execute SQL script you can use dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand or dbContext.Database.SqlQuery. If you need more info about EF watch my tutorial about EF in arabic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLxLonR9qCA

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Accounts
```

and then if you get e.g. 111111111 run

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(tbl, RESEED, 111111112)
```

Seems like your identity column has a wrong seed.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278605/2224701).